# How to fix broken monitor's consistently periodic lines and distortion?

Tags: display, hdmi

My cat gnawed on the corner of my computer monitor and now it goes through a very regular cycle of 2 seconds being fine and 2 seconds being distorted and fuzzy (in addition to some pixels in the corner being constantly white, where she chewed).

Here it is fuzzy (notice the ghosting of the repeated "Living Room TV"):

[image]

and here it is (mostly) OK:

[image]

There's a bit of swirly colors in both pictures, which is just an artifact of photographing the monitor and not present in real life. In the fuzzy scenario, it's all weird horizontal and duplicated lines that are the problem.

The monitor is clearly damaged at the hardware level, but what's odd to me is how repeated and regular the fuzziness is, and how when it's not broken, it's (almost, except for the corner) perfectly fine. That gives me hope that there's a way to salvage it.

Right now my Chromecast is hooked up to it over HDMI. When my laptop is hooked up on HDMI the issue is the same. Is there some setting perhaps that relates to the signal changing every couple seconds? Is there something I could do that would "lock" it into the good mode?

In case it's relevant, the unapologetic source of the damage:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speculative answer.

Newer flat-screen monitors can be quite thin, and therefore are a bit flimsy.  If their frames were to be bent, twisted, or were to come apart a bit, (maybe a lost screw, or other damage), then some of the vertical columns of tiny electrical contacts that exist under the sides of the screen can become disconnected, so that certain rows of pixels won't light up.

Try this:

With your hand, squeeze the upper right corner of the monitor gently but firmly, (while it's showing an image of course), and see if that helps.  Also see if similar squeezing along the right edge doesn't help.  Pressure from both hands might be needed.

If that improves the picture, try clamping two flat wooden slats on the right edge of the monitor.

The longer term fix/kludge would be to correct or reinforce whatever's holding the right side of the monitor together.

Comment: That worked!!!! I noticed when I pressed firmly on the right hand side it "crunched" and now it's permanently broken where I pressed, but the whole monitor to the left of it cleared up. So pressing firmly, I slid my thumbs down the right side, crunching as it went, and now the right inch or so of the monitor is destroyed, but the whole rest of the monitor is consistently cleared! There's some life yet in this thing. Thanks so much!!!